# IE jQuery object error SCRIPT5007

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am trying to access JQuery object variable

```
var items = [];
function Item(id, position, content) {
  this.id = id;
  this.position = position;
  this.content = content;
}
```

I am creating an new element by

```
items.push(new Item(1, [0, 40], 'asd');
```

then i and looping through all items in the array, when calling

```
item[i].position[0]
```

I am getting an error `SCRIPT5007`. In Chrome and FF this is working fine, only problem is with IE.

Comment: Have you put a debugger line inside your loop. This should give you more info.

Comment: Do you open the page via `http://` or `file://`?

Comment: Please, could you add the description of the "SCRIPT5007" reported by IE11?

Comment: SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your `header`

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" >
```

It will work!!

Comment: IE 11.0.9600.17728 (KB3038314)

Comment: Why I feel that you are missing a bracket in this line `items.push(new Item(1, [0, 40], 'asd')`?? It should have been `items.push(new Item(1, [0, 40], 'asd'))`!!

Comment: Yes, that's true. It was an copy paste fail. But the error is still there. I have tried to google it around without an success.

Answer (score 0):

I tried it on my local system now. They are 2 errors:

1. The known missing `)`:

`items.push(new Item(1, [0, 40], 'asd');`

to

`items.push(new Item(1, [0, 40], 'asd'));`

2. You calling for the wrong var name

`item[0].position[0]`

to

`items[0].position[0]`

Tried it localy and it works fine!